# Assembly Stack behaviour

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

```
Cfunction: push rbp
           push r9
           push r8
           push rcx
           push rdx
           push rsi
           mov rbx, rsp
```

I'm trying to get the value of the 7th parameter in an external C driver file containing the parameters (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7). I'm completely new to assembly and thus out of ideas. As to my knowledge [rbp + 16] should contain the value of the 7th parameter but instead for some reason [rbp +16] is equal to an empty string instead of '7'. So does anyone have an explanation towards why [rbp + 16] does not point to the 7th parameter on the stack and have any solution to where the 7th parameter is being pushed? (Using NASM on 64 bit linux)

Comment: You didn't even set up `rbp`, so no telling where it's pointing. Maybe the last line is a typo and you meant `rbp` not `rbx`. Even so, `rbp+16` is certainly not your argument, that's actually the `rcx` value saved by `push rcx`.

Comment: I got it working, thanks

Comment: The 7th arg is on the stack at `[rsp+8]` on function entry (before you push anything), right above the return address.  (Unless it's a floating-point arg, in which case it's in `xmm0`).